# Switching between cameras in blueprints

Tags: camera, blueprints

I'm hoping that someone can help me, I have a blueprint called `BP_NPC_Shop` that holds some objects and a box collision, when the player runs over that box collision they can press <kbd>E</kbd> to trigger an event.  In my case I want to switch the camera from the `ThirdPersonCharacter` blueprint camera to the camera in my `BP_NPC_Shop` blueprint.

I setup all the logic within the event graph of the `BP_NPC_Shop` (input action works is the switching of the camera that doesn't).
[image]

So, when <kbd>E</kbd> is pressed, we see a string that reflects that, the camera is then meant to switch from the player to the `BP_NPC_Shop`.  I created an object reference to that blueprint and used it as the new view target, it was my understanding that when using "Set view target with blend" it will look for the first camera it finds within a reference blueprint.

The problem I am facing is that when I press <kbd>E</kbd> on the box collision, the camera switches to a first person view.

Cameras normal position (2.5d game)
[[image]

Camera switch (wrong camera as this is not the shop camera)
[image]

Is the manner in which I'm doing this wrong and what can I change to make this work correctly?